# How to create an article -> issue -> magazine hierarchical structure with Entity Reference?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to [create](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167533/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-reference-based-modules-instea) a magazine archive website.

The structure is like that: **article <- issue <- magazine**.

All of these are different content types.

What I want to do is to create a **hierarchy** while adding articles.

*Each issue is referenced to a magazine.*

*Each article is referenced to an issue (and dependently to a magazine).*

#### While creating an article I want to select the magazine (referenced field) and then select the issue (referenced field) based on the magazine.

How can I do this?

*(I tried both the [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) and [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) modules but they do not do what I want.)*

[image]

Comment: is there any reason you use content types for issue and magazine?

Comment: @sam2de good question :) I asked this on that (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167533/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-reference-based-modules-instea) question and the answer was to make them content type not taxonomy term. Any suggestion from you? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend making magazine and issue as a taxonomies and use Hierarchical Select field in the article content type.

Comment: @sam2de but magazine and issue have fields. Although taxonomy terms can have fields I'm told using content types would be better. Now, if I couldn't a good way for hierarchical selection I will use taxonomy terms again, as always. Thanks.

Comment: @Mołot thanks. Yes, it seems duplicate and interestingly I haven't seen it although I search the site. I will deeply check it and will share the results.