# How can I limit the Field 2 according to value of Field 1 while creating the nodes via Feeds module?

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I have three content types **A**, B and C.

The content type A has two entity reference field (I'm using the [Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules for that).

## Content Type A

- Field 1 (refers to entity type C)
- Field 2 (refers to entity type B)

## Content Type B

- Field 1 (refers to entity type C)

I'm also using the [Reference Field Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module to limit the Field X.

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their
>   widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in
>   the current entity.

Everything is OK while creating the nodes manually.

I'm creating the content type C's, then creating the content type B's and referencing these to content type C.
Then, I'm creating the content type A and first select the Field 1 (refers to entity type C) and then the options of Field 2 limited according to value of Field 1 and then I select.

But... while creating the nodes with the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module I couldn't limit the Field 2.

**My question**: How can I limit the Field 2 according to value of Field 1 while creating the nodes via Feeds module?

**Note**: What I'm trying to do is detailed in my question "[How to create an article -> issue -> magazine hierarchical structure with Entity Reference?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171233)".