# Multiple node reference

Tags: 7, nodes

This might be covered in another question but I couldn't find one with the same scenario I have, if there is one just point me to it please.

To make it simple I have 2 content types: Persons and Organisation

One thing admins should be able to enter about each person is how they are related to one or more organisations. So my first idea was to simply make a node-reference field with unlimited values and that should solve everything.

The problem is that for each of this connections I have to enter multiple fields. When I make a reference from a person I need to enter:

- The reference itself
- The type of relationship (employee, volunteer,
  board member)
- The level of the role played in the organisation
- The position (text field) So, every time I make a "Add another field" I
  should actually be adding 4 field and they all need to be "kept
  together".

What is the best way to do this?

I was suggested to use the [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module but I understand that it messes a lot with drupal structure and I want to keep things clean. I'm also worried how [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) is going to work to a module like that.

I was also suggested to do a new reference content type in which I reference the Person node, the Organisation node and then the extra information fields. I think this is the "cleanest" way but the thing is... how do I make it easy for admins to be able to make this references while they are adding a new person? or if the person must be saved first to have a node id, immediately after and not just present a add node form after the other one (the admin will need to enter between 5 and 10 references and I don't want to make 10 redirects)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this page, it gives some good idea http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167533/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-reference-based-modules-instea/167776#167776

Comment: @Drupalist do you know if [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module is doing this? Field Collection does not have stable release for 7, and no release for 8 at all.

Comment: @Mołot It has been  a long time I am using Field Collection and it has no inconsistency, it is working very well.


From what I know the Field Group module is just to group the fields when the user is adding new content, it has nothing to do with the relationship between contents at all